# Using Watson Cloud function, Specifically Translate language and return the json result to Watson assistant

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson

Good Day, I have another question related to the above thread.

I am using he same below code to run watson language translator. In my case, I need to return the code response to watson assistant. I dont know how but I know that I need to use the return to respond back to function variable.

My question is, how to return the json result into a function variable ? my intention is to return the translated text back to watson assistant.

I found one link but its an old one and needs to be updated. It uses the language translator packages and it builds 7 actions. The code in the translation action is not clear for me, although I read the documentation multiple times. How can I use the below code section 1 to translate a text and return the result to my watson instance?

I hope this is clear enough..

----------- section 1 code starts--------

```
const LanguageTranslatorV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/language-translator/v3');
const extend = require('extend');
const vcap = require('vcap_services');

/**
 * Translate.
 *
 * Translates the input text from the source language to the target language.
 *
 * @param {Object} params - The parameters to send to the service.
 * @param {string} [params.username] - The username used to authenticate with the service. Username and password credentials are only required to run your application locally or outside of Bluemix. When running on Bluemix, the credentials will be automatically loaded from the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable.
 * @param {string} [params.password] - The password used to authenticate with the service. Username and password credentials are only required to run your application locally or outside of Bluemix. When running on Bluemix, the credentials will be automatically loaded from the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable.
 * @param {string} [params.iam_access_token] - An IAM access token fully managed by the application. Responsibility falls on the application to refresh the token, either before it expires or reactively upon receiving a 401 from the service, as any requests made with an expired token will fail.
 * @param {string} [params.iam_apikey] - An API key that can be used to request IAM tokens. If this API key is provided, the SDK will manage the token and handle the refreshing.
 * @param {string} [params.iam_url] - An optional URL for the IAM service API. Defaults to 'https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token'.
 * @param {Object} [params.headers] - Custom HTTP request headers
 * @param {boolean} [params.headers.X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out=false] - opt-out of data collection
 * @param {string} [params.url] - override default service base url
 * @param {string} params.version - Release date of the API version in YYYY-MM-DD format.
 * @param {string[]} params.text - Input text in UTF-8 encoding. Multiple entries will result in multiple translations
 * in the response.
 * @param {string} [params.model_id] - Model ID of the translation model to use. If this is specified, the **source**
 * and **target** parameters will be ignored. The method requires either a model ID or both the **source** and
 * **target** parameters.
 * @param {string} [params.source] - Language code of the source text language. Use with `target` as an alternative way
 * to select a translation model. When `source` and `target` are set, and a model ID is not set, the system chooses a
 * default model for the language pair (usually the model based on the news domain).
 * @param {string} [params.target] - Language code of the translation target language. Use with source as an alternative
 * way to select a translation model.
 * @return {Promise} - The Promise that the action returns.
 */
function main(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const _params = vcap.getCredentialsFromServiceBind(
      params,
      'language-translator',
      'language_translator'
    );
    _params.headers = extend(
      {},
      _params.headers,
      { 'User-Agent': 'openwhisk' }
    );
    let service;
    try {
      service = new LanguageTranslatorV3(_params);
      service.translate(_params, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err.message);
        } else {
          resolve(response);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err.message);
      return;
    }
  });
}

global.main = main;
module.exports.test = main;
```

------------code end-------------------

Comment: It seems you accidentaly exposed your apikey and service url endpoint in the question, for obvious security reasons you should remove this question and create a new one censoring the sensitive information and promptly generate a new apikey for your Watson Translator instance.

Comment: thanks, but what can anyone do with the endpoint without the apikey, the apikey is masked - notice the last segment is marked with * .

Comment: Im new to all this, what about my original question, is it clear? or its a bit confusing?